How to fix my envelope detector script
I am 17 years old. I'm still in 12th grade. However, I love discovering new things and learning so I can be a more informed person.
So, it was suggested to me that I try to script an envelope detector in NGSpice and I have already created an AM signal. Even so, I can't do the upper envelope.
I actually just updated my script:
Moreover, I am trying to make a loop in which I can see the results of different values of the capacitor.
Now I readjusted the value of the AM signal. Is it suitable? Does it respect the condition mentioned by @Carl?
* Fonte AM
 V1 0 1 AM(0 0 100k 0.05k 1k 0 0 0)  * Frequência de portadora ajustada para 100 kHz
* Componentes
D1 1 2 DBAT15
C1 2 0 0.1u
R1 2 0 10k
 
* Modelos do díodos
.model 1N4148W D(IS=10.4n RS=51.5m BV=75.0 IBV=1.00u
     + CJO=2.00p M=0.333 N=2.07 TT=5.76n)
 
.model DBAT15 D(Is=1e-14 Rs=0.1 Cjo=1e-12 M=0.33
     + N=1.05 Vj=0.3 Eg=1.11)
 
* Análise transiente
.tran 0.01ms 20ms
 

.control
    let ix = 0
    set curva = " " 

    * Loop para variação de C1
    foreach val 0u 0.1u 0.2u 0.3u 0.4u 3u 
        echo **************************************
        let ix = ix + 1
        echo var is $val 
        alter C1 $val
        run     
        linearize 
        let v_2_3 = v(2) 
        set curva = ( $curva  {$curplot}.v_2_3 ) 
        echo indice é $&ix 
        echo **************************************
        echo $curplot
    end
    echo $curva 
    plot v(1) 

* Configuração de saída gráfica para imagem PNG
set nolegend
set xbrushwidth=2
set gnuplot_terminal=png pngcairo transparent/quit
set gnuplot_terminal=png size 1024,768
set title "Gráfico de Multi-Curvas para Variação de C1"
gnuplot circuito $curva v(1)
* rusage
quit
.endc

.end
***************************************

Well I tried to respect the rule that @Carl mentioned.
Also, what do you think of the resistor values?
I am supposed to create an upper envelope (https://www.google.com/imgres?q=upper%20envelope&imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F3%2F31%2FSignal_envelopes.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEnvelope_(waves)&docid=6MMsCaXDLt9O1M&tbnid=FF4w8nn1KLt04M&vet=12ahUKEwjLwpr82LGKAxVcRKQEHU2nBVIQM3oECB0QAA..i&w=602&h=378&hcb=2&ved=2ahUKEwjLwpr82LGKAxVcRKQEHU2nBVIQM3oECB0QAA ) and according to my calculations, the most suitable value for the capacitor is 3uF. What do you think? Should I increase it?
This is my circuit:
This is my output signal: 

Hi! And welcome here! It's fantastic you're working at this level!

could you do us the favor and add the schematic belonging to this simulation to your question, as well as the plot of the output? (I ask because I had to take out a pen and a piece of paper and draw the circuit from the connections as specified in your SPICE script. For the others: this is a series of a diode, a capacitor and a resistor. "unconnected" side of diode is fed with ground-referenced AM signal, "unconnected" end of resistor connected to ground. Observed output voltage is that over the resistor.)

Ok, I'll add the schematics as an answer... I'm sure it's not the right solution, but I'm not yet an expert on this platform, sorry

Actually, I could add it by editing my question :)

exactly, add it by editing your question! :) That's the right way!

hm, is your schematic really the same as your simulation? In your simulation, C1 is connected between n4 and n5, i.e., between D1 and R1, and not to ground.

Like that?
.model DBAT46 D(Is=2.2e-8 Rs=0.1 Cjo=2e-12 M=0.33 N=1.05 Vj=0.7 Eg=0.69)
D1 n3 n4 DBAT46                   ; Diodo BAT46 para retificação
C1 n4 0 {C}                        ; Condensador ligado ao terra (0) para suavização do envelope
R1 n5 0 {R}                        ; Resistência para descarregamento lento    I apologize if I'm wrong, I'm still in the process of learning how to program spice

can't really decipher that.

.model DBAT46 D(Is=2.2e-8 Rs=0.1 Cjo=2e-12 M=0.33 N=1.05 Vj=0.7 Eg=0.69)
D1 n3 n4 DBAT46
C1 n4 0 {C}
R1 n5 0 {R}
Are these the correct connections? Now when I try to run the code, v(n5) is set to y=0

Can't personally parse SPICE without line breaks, sorry.

Ok I will edit on the question

now R1 seems to be completely unconnected to the other two? You'll need to fix your netlist and verify it's correct. It's not hard to but the n1,…n5 on your schematic where they are according to your SPICE code and check whether they are incomplete or self-contradictory :)

OK, I will try my best so as to improve my code and when I feel there is some improvement then I tell you something:) Thanhs a lot

Why are you applying an envelope detector to a suppressed carrier modulated signal? Envelope detectors cannot be used this way to recover the baseband modulating signal.

To maintain the integrity of the message signal when detecting the envelope, this inequality must be satisfied
$$B < \frac{1}{2\pi RC} \ll f_c \tag1$$
\$B\$ is the bandwidth of your message signal (in this case 5 kHz), and \$f_c\$ is the frequency of your carrier.
You have chosen \$R=100 \: \text{k}\Omega\$ and \$C = 10 \: \mu\text{F}\$, which yields a time constant of \$\tau = \frac{1}{RC} = 1 \: \text{s} \$. This value does not satisify the inequality in (1). You should try to decrease the value of your capacitor significantly. Also, you could also try increasing your carrier frequency to a much higher value.

Thank you very much, I will follow your tips, very useful

A few problems, one of which @Carl has addressed.
Marcus has pointed out the other problem with SPICE netlist nodes:
The SPICE netlist for this schematic would correspond to the schematic above. \$V_{in}\$ at node #3 is not included here:
D1 n3 n4 DBAT46                   ; Diodo BAT46 para retificação
C1 n4 0 {C}                       ; Condensador ligado ao terra (0) 
R1 n4 0 {R}                       ; Resistência para descarregamento 

Demodulator output \$V_{out}\$ is now node #4, not node #5, and node #4 voltage is the one you would plot as output.
Since modulation of 5kHz is close to carrier frequency of 50 kHz, choice of the RC time constant in the demodulator filter is fairly tightly constrained. If R=100k, capacitance C would better be in the nanofarad region.

* Fonte AM
V1 0 1 AM(0 0 12 0.05k 1k 0 0 0)

* Componentes
D1 1 2 DBAT15
C1 2 0 0.1u
R1 2 0 10k

* Modelos do díodos
.model DBAT15 D(Is=1e-14 Rs=0.1 Cjo=1e-12 M=0.33 
     + N=1.05 Vj=0.3 Eg=1.11)

* Análise transiente
.tran 0.01ms 20ms

.control
    run
    set xbrushwidth=2
    set gnuplot_terminal=png pngcairo transparent/quit
    gnuplot marta02 v(1)  v(2)
*     plot v(1) v(2)
    quit
.endc


I edited the answer to format the script as code to make it readable. However, there is no explanation of how the script answers the question. Consider editing the answer to include a description of how it answers the question.
